# Can not execute stored procedure from very simple query string

Tags: sql, sql-server, execute

I have just very simple query. When I run strange that query with `SELECT` statement, everything is ok, but if I replace that statement with a function call for a string variable, it throws wrong with the message:

> Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 133
>   Could not find stored procedure 'select * from @aTable'.

The code is very simple as i said:

```
 DECLARE @sqlString varchar(max)

 SET @sqlString = 'select * from @aTable'

 EXEC @sqlString        //something wrong with warning: Could not find stored procedure 'select * from @aTable'
```

When I run this code, it goes wrong, but when I run strange code, it works:

```
SELECT * FROM @aTable     //it run smoothly
```

I really see nothing about the wrong

Comment: You need parentheses:  `exec(@sqlString)` or use `sp_executesql`.  However, that will probably just lead you to further problems.

Comment: Unless you've got a compelling reason to use them, dynamic queries are a bad idea for performance because the execution plans can not be effectively cached. Have you considered passing parameters to your stored proc instead?

Comment: i have change the code as you said, and as you said, another problem appear with warning: Must declare the table variable "@aTable".

Comment: @Greg  i will try it later, but could you say about what the problem of my code? just a simple dynamic query but it can not run.

Comment: The error message is saying that you haven't declared the table variable @aTable. What table are you trying to interrogate? The @ symbol indicates that it is a variable but there is no variable defined in your code.

Comment: offcouse i have declare the @aTable variable, so when i run "SELECT * FROM @aTable", it run